# Sitecore 10.1 | Site resolving works only if I check "Enable Preview" site property (for items referenced from different site)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I have multiple sites architecture. Like this one

*sitecore/content/site1*
*sitecore/content/site2*

For each item of site2 referenced in site1 I get the following URL:

*[www.site1.com/sitecore/content/site2/item](http://www.site1.com/sitecore/content/site2/item)*

instead of

*[www.site2.com/item](http://www.site2.com/item)*

I've debugged **Sitecore.Sites.DefaultItemSiteResolver** and found, that the site can be only resolved only if it has "Enable Preview" site property set to true:

[image]

But now, after setting it to true, I have another problem, the page resolving now works also in the preview (which is not the desired behavior, I want only the "webiste" site to be resolved there). It even ignores the "Preview.ResolveSite" setting, which is set to false.

What am I doing wrong? How to enable site resolving for published sites but not for the preview?

Answer (score 1):

There are several settings in `Sitecore.config` that help to configure proper site resolving logic in multisite Sitecore solutions:

- `Rendering.SiteResolving` — enables site resolving, so cross-site links can be rendered with correct hostname, language, and virtual folder.
- `Rendering.SiteResolvingMatchCurrentSite` — item location is taken into consideration when a cross-site link is built. All items under a certain site root will be resolved in the context of that root.
- `Rendering.SiteResolvingMatchCurrentLanguage` — when true, context language is taken into consideration when a cross-site link is built.

It is recommended to keep the `Rendering.SiteResolving` setting value at `true` for any multisite solution in order to ensure that cross-site links are built with the correct parameters. In this case, the Experience Editor and Preview mode are opened in the context of the site defined in the `Preview.DefaultSite` setting, if no other site can be resolved.

To make sure that items are opened in context of correct site, you must set the `Rendering.SiteResolvingMatchCurrentSite` setting to `true`.